# Switched from DAO to ADO and SQL query now returns an error, any ideas?

Tags: sql, ado, dao

I was using the following code to query my database in DAO, which worked fine:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (Resources LEFT JOIN [Select * FROM AvailabilityBlocks LEFT JOIN Location ON AvailabilityBlocks.LocationID=Location.LocationID WHERE ((CStr(AvailabilityBlocks.LocationID) IN ('8', '14', '16', '1', '15', '17', '10', '9', '19', '12', '5', '18', '13', '20', '3', '26', '2', '25', '28', '27') AND (AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 3 OR AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 4)) OR AvailabilityBlocks.Type = 2) AND Begin < #15-Jul-2013 12:00:00 AM# And Begin >= #08-Jul-2013 12:00:00 AM#]. AS FilteredTable ON Resources.ResourceID=FilteredTable.ResourceID) LEFT JOIN EmployeeTypes ON EmployeeTypes.TypeID=Resources.EmployeeType ORDER BY RClass, Resources.LastName ASC, Resources.FirstName ASC, Resources.ResourceID ASC, AvailabilityBlocks.Begin ASC, AvailabilityBlocks.End Desc, Location.SubType DESC
```

I then converted all my code to ADO and the SQL stopped working and now shows an

> Syntax error in FROM clause.

error message!

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: We need to know what the backend RDBMS is.  Or ... that thing called JET (mdb/access) if that the case.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of JET!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
I think the way your are closing out your derived table ("FilteredTable") is off.
Also.  You might want to try a table alias...

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
Resources res 
LEFT JOIN (
[Select * FROM AvailabilityBlocks avb LEFT JOIN Location loc ON avb.locID=loc.locID 
WHERE ((CStr(avb.locID) IN ('8', '14', '16', '1', '15', '17', '10', '9', '19', '12', '5', '18', '13', '20', '3', '26', '2', '25', '28', '27') 
AND (avb.Type = 3 OR avb.Type = 4)) OR avb.Type = 2) 
AND Begin < #15-Jul-2013 12:00:00 AM# And Begin >= #08-Jul-2013 12:00:00 AM#] ) AS FilteredTable 
ON res.ResourceID=FilteredTable.ResourceID) 

LEFT JOIN EmployeeTypes ON EmployeeTypes.TypeID=res.EmployeeType 

ORDER BY RClass, res.LastName ASC, res.FirstName ASC, res.ResourceID ASC, avb.Begin ASC, avb.End Desc, loc.SubType DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't work either..if I try to execute the query directly in MS Access the "]" is highlighted and error is still Syntax error in FROM clause! Any other ideas?